# SublimeREPL doesn`t recognize python libs

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I'm trying to run python code from Sublime Text 2 with SublimeREPL.

But when I call a package from Sublime, Python returns a message that there is no package.
e.g.

```
from facebookads.session import FacebookSession 
ImportError: No module named facebookads.session
```

This works fine if I import from python in Terminal.

When I start python from sublimeREPL it says:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
```

And when I start Python from Terminal (I'm running on a OS X Yosemite)

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jan 11 2014, 11:50:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
```

What is wrong?
Why this difference on default dates?

**EDIT**

if I run

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
```

on SublimeREPL I get this:

```
'/usr/bin/python'
```

And on Terminal I get this:

```
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python'
```

I changed my User Settings of SublimeREPL

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python:{PATH}"}
}
```

And I'm still getting the same results. SublimeREPL didn't change the interpreter.

**EDIT2**

When I run

```
ls -al /usr/local/bin/python
```

I get

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 filipeferminiano  admin  33 Jan 11  2014 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/python
```

I tried:

```
brew link python
```

But it returned:

```
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

I tried again:

```
ls -al /usr/local/bin/python
```

And got the same result from before

Comment: You are using two different interpreters

Comment: Sublime and your terminal are using two different pythons, each with their own set of packages.

Comment: How can I change sublimeREPL to read the same python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using two different interpreters. You can check it by running following lines inside SublimeREPL and interpreter you run from console (paths will be different):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python'
```

If values are different you should change SublimeREPL settings to point to correct interpreter (the same as you got, when run Python from console). One way to achieve it is to modify PATH variable used by SublimeREPL. Go to Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeREPL -> Settings - User and prepend directory with your wanted interpreter to the `default_extend_env` setting (don't forget to remove `python` from the end). With interpreter from my example it looks like this:

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/:{PATH}"}
}
```

But much better approach is to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to manage your Python environments. You can start interpreter for proper environment by executing "SublimeREPL: Python - virtualenv" instead of "SublimeREPL: Python". See [documentation](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#python).

Comment: thanks for help @devoto13 I edited my question. SublimeREPL isn't changng the python interpreter.

Comment: Can you please post an ouput from the following command `ls -al /usr/local/bin/python`? It should be a symlink to you interpreter path `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`. If it's not, try to run `brew link python` and recheck again. If it's the case, you can prepend `/usr/local/bin/` instead of the long path in SublimeREPL settings.

Comment: Your symlink looks fine. I think setting `default_extend_env` to `{"PATH": "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/:{PATH}"}` should fix problem for you. Both interpreters are using the same packages.